# google ml engine scale-tier not running in remote distributed training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, distributed

When running tensorflow with REMOTE distributed command:
after specifying "scale-tier STANDARD_1". Batch failed to run....
Now, I can ONLY run with simple SINGLE NODE "scale-tier=BASIC"

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training census_20171005_162623
--stream-logs --scale-tier STANDARD_1 --staging-bucket gs://dextest --runtime-version 1.2 --job-
dir gs://dextest/census_20171005_162623 --module-name trainer.task --package-path trainer/ --
region us-central1 -- --train-files
gs://cloudml-public/census/data/adult.data.csv --eval-files
gs://cloudml-public/census/data/adult.test.csv --train-steps 1000
--eval-steps 100
```

The error I am getting is

```
The replica worker 1 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error.
```

From the log:

> Retrying after gsutil exception Command '['gsutil', '-q', 'cp',
>    u'gs://dextest/census_20171005_161531/2211a814b974edbc3defee855046dd8e801393b7ff8154b084b081322167fe90/trainer-0.0.0.tar.gz',
>   u'trainer-0.0.0.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

The Master did SUCCESSFULLY initialized and copued the package "trainer-0.0.0.tar.gz"
However, issue happened when replicas copying package for the run.
It seems that the ML workflow FAILED to handle the cleanup in replicas....
The replicas tried to clean the job directory 
"gs://dextest/census_20171005_162623"
again before running.

the error happened after master copy the package and
the replicas FAILED to pick up the package for running.

> I  CommandException: No URLs matched:
>   gs://dextest/census_20171005_161531/2211a814b974edbc3defee855046dd8e801393b7ff8154b084b081322167fe90/trainer-0.0.0.tar.gz
>   E  Retrying after gsutil exception Command '['gsutil', '-q', 'cp',
>   u'gs://dextest/census_20171005_161531/2211a814b974edbc3defee855046dd8e801393b7ff8154b084b081322167fe90/trainer-0.0.0.tar.gz',
>   u'trainer-0.0.0.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
>   undefined

Answer (score 2):

It is evident from your error message ("The replica worker 1 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error.") that you have some programming error (syntax, undefined etc).

Check the [return code table](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/troubleshooting)

```
Return code -------------Meaning--------------- Cloud ML Engine response

0   Successful completion   Shuts down and releases job resources.
1 - 128 Unrecoverable error Ends the job and logs the error.
```

Find the bug and fix it and then try again.

I recommend run your task locally (if your configuration supports) before you submit in cloud. If you find any bug, you can fix easily in your local machine.